# how to get the value of child attributes from xml and add the same attributes to parent node using xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am pretty much new to Xslt where I want to convert one xml which  child node has an attribute I would like to put it on parent .So far I tried reading the attribute value  store in  a variable but it seems it does not help as variable scope willnot be valid

XML Sample :

```
<Parent>
 <CHILD_1>
      <SUBCHILD ATTR="345">
      <element1>10</element1>
      </SUBCHILD >
    <CHILD_1>
</Parent>
```

I want to putthe Attribute attr as an attribute of parent and remove it from child_1 .

What i tried :

```
   <xsl:template match="Parent">
      <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="ATTR" select="CHILD_1/SUBCHILD /@ATTR"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>
```

This is adding attribute on parent node but not removing attribute from child

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to the to be removed attribute does the trick

```
<xsl:template match="@ATTR"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to traverse only node elements and address attributes specifically. This will eliminate the attributes to be added by the recursive templates

Demo for you : http://xsltransform.net/ejivdHb/20

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns1="http://locomotive/bypass/docx" >
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="CHILD_1">
    <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:attribute name="role" select="SUBCHILD/@ATTR"/>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```